# How to mock redis connection in Go

Tags: go, redis, mocking

I am using `https://github.com/go-redis/redis` package to make Redis DB calls.

For unit testing I want to mock these calls, is there any mock library or way to do it?

Comment: you can create an interface with all the methods you use from redis, and use the interface instead of the redis references. With that you can create a struct how follows the interface specs and use it in your methods

Comment: https://github.com/rafaeljusto/redigomock

Comment: Please choose one of the answers.

Answer (score 22):

It's even easier to mock using [miniredis](http://github.com/alicebob/miniredis) than is apparent. You don't need to mock every function like Get, Set, ZAdd, etc. You can start the `miniredis` and inject its address to the actual client being used in code (e.g. [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis)) this way:

```golang
server := miniredis.Run()
redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr: server.Addr(),
})
```

No further mocking would be required. This also enables you to seamlessly use `Pipelined()`, `TxPipelined()` etc. even though `miniredis` doesn't explicitly expose these methods.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you all for the response. I found this package https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis very useful for redis mocking.

Answer (score 1):

as @Motakjuq said, create an interface like this

```
type DB interface {
   GetData(key string) (value string, error)
   SetData(key string, value string) error
}
```

and implement it with actual redis client (like [this](https://github.com/go-redis/redis)) in your code and [miniredis](https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis) in tests.